# InstallShield 2008 Premier Edition - GitHub plug-in available?

Tags: github, installshield

does anyone know if there is a GitHub plug-in available for InstallShield 2008 Premier Edition? I haven't had much luck googling it. I submitted a question to GitHub Support and they actually suggested submitting a question on Stack Overflow (which I likely would have done anyway). If anyone can assist it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,

Randy Maddocks

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield supports MSSCCI plugins on its own, or when used inside Visual Studio, InstallShield can interact with the source control provider used by Visual Studio.

I don't believe there are any MSSCCI GitHub plugins, and I'm unclear whether you have Visual Studio. Personally I find it straightforward to work with the GitHub desktop client.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very much appreciated. I will definitely look into using the GitHub desktop client.